# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'? What should i do?

Tags: django

I am extending User model of Django by following model
models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    First_name = models.CharField(max_length = 128, null = True)
    Last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 128, null = True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
def userprofile(request):
    form = Profile()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Profile(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'cs14/profile.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class Profile(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["First_name","Last_name","email", "phone"]
```

When I try to go profile page, it happened error

```
AttributeError at /profile/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'
```

What is going wrong? After I change the User null = false, it shows RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at the profile. Profile has no user.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body_block %}

<style>
    .profile-pic{
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
</style>

<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class ="card card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'home:index'%}"> &#8592; Back to homepage</a>
            <hr>
            <h3 style="text-align: center">User profile</h3>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <img class="profile-pic" src="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <table>
                    {{form}}
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you have set null=False for user in Profile model but not passing while saving profile model.

Comment: Show your profile page.

Answer (score 0):

can you show what you have wrote in profile.html, btw, it's better to use the emailField in :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    First_name = models.CharField(max_length = 128, null = True)
    Last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 128, null = True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
```

and since the user attribute can't be null you have to specify the user in the view userprofil function like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Profile(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.user = request.user
        form.save()
```

but if you are trying to get the username in profile page, your passing the profile object in the context which doesn't have the username attribute.

Comment: So what I want to do is let the user update their profile and pictures. It works in Django backend but fails in profile.html

Comment: After I change null = True to False, it show RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at profile.Profile has no user.